# How to change text color in Action bar using theme and Theme.AppCompat.DayNight

Tags: android, themes, statusbar

I am trying to change the text color of the text in Default Action Bar using Theme. I can easily change the background of the Status Bar, but whatever I do, the text stays the same in Action Bar:

[image]

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.MyAapp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ocean</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/light_ocean</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/ocean</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/dark_ocean</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/ocean</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Is it possible to override it in Theme.AppCompat.DayNight? I need to use this theme. I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Hello this is a map for you.  If you do not have some of them, you must define it

[image: this is a map for you]

Comment: So simple and so awesome. Thank you.

Comment: glad to help @Konard!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     <!-- Base application theme. -->
>     <style name="Theme.MyAapp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
>         <!-- Primary brand color. -->
>
>         <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ocean</item>
>         <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/light_ocean</item>
>         <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
>         <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
>         <item name="colorSecondary">@color/ocean</item>
>         <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/dark_ocean</item>
>         <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/ocean</item>
>         <!-- Status bar color. -->
>         <!-- Status bar color. -->
>         <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
>         <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
>
>         <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.ActionBar</item>
>     </style>
>
>     <style name="hemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.ActionBar"  parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar">
>         <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
>     </style>
> ```

Comment: I will definitely use it when the first option will not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define toolbar_style with parent: Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar like this example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/highlightRed</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/toolbar_style</item>
</style>


<style name="toolbar_style" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```